# sales_order_place_before Showing Exceptions

Tags: magento-1.7, error, sales-order

This code is showing exception even when the condition is not true!!

Please can anyone help where I am wrong

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Fooman_Example>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Fooman_Example>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <fooman_example>
                <class>Fooman_Example_Model</class>
            </fooman_example>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <fooman_example>
                <class>Fooman_Example_Helper</class>
            </fooman_example>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options>
                <observers>
                    <fooman_example_catalog_product_type_prepare>
                        <class>Fooman_Example_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>catalogProductTypePrepare</method>
                    </fooman_example_catalog_product_type_prepare>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options>
            <sales_order_place_before>
                <observers>
                    <fooman_example_order_observer>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>Fooman_Example_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>AddProductSaveBefore</method>
                    </fooman_example_order_observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_before>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**Observer:**

```
<?php

class Fooman_Example_Model_Observer
{
    public function catalogProductTypePrepare($observer)
    {
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        if ($quote->getItemsCount() >= 1) {
            Mage::throwException('You can only buy one product at a time.');
        }
    }

    public function AddProductSaveBefore($observer)
    {
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
            $customerId = $customerData->getId();

            $fromDate = date('2016-09-10 00:00:00');
            $toDate = date('2016-09-10 23:59:59');
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate));
        }


        if ($quote->getItemsCount() >= 1) {
            Mage::throwException('You can only Buy one product at a time. Please Change your Cart Items.');
        }
        if (count($order) >= 1) {
            Mage::throwException('You already ordered today');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change this lines:

```
if ($quote->getItemsCount() >= 1) {
    Mage::throwException('You can only Buy one product at a time. Please Change your Cart Items.');
}
```

to the:

```
if ($quote->getItemsCount() > 1) { // changes in condition
    Mage::throwException('You can only Buy one product at a time. Please Change your Cart Items.');
}
```

I think an error comes from your conditions: all quotes has at least an one item, but in your case you restrict ability to add >= 1 item to the quote. This solution can be acceptable for you if your purpose consists in limiting ability to add more than one item at one time to the shopping cart.

Additional try to change this condition:

```
if (count($order) >= 1) {
    Mage::throwException('You already ordered today');
}
```

to the:

```
if (count($order->getItems()) >= 1) {
    Mage::throwException('You already ordered today');
}
```

#### Update:

If you want to restrict adding more than one product of one item (qty) you should use the `if ($quote->getItemsQty() >= 1) {...` condition.

[image: $quote->getItemsQty()]

To get last 24h orders count for specified customer use the next code:

```
$time = time();
$toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
$lastTime = $time - 86400; // 60*60*24
$fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lastTime);
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate))
    ->load();
```

The result query (for the collection) should be like this:

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table` WHERE (main_table.customer_id = '140') AND (created_at >= '2016-09-09 12:33:00' AND created_at <= '2016-09-10 12:33:00')
```

and as your new order was already created you should remove 1 from the order count inside the if condition:

```
if ((count($order->getItems()) - 1) >= 1) {
    Mage::throwException('You already ordered today');
}
```

or try to use another event, before order was saved.

Result in the debug:

[image: Result in the debug]

Comment: yeah Right! But its showing second exception now! Why is That?

Comment: @Lalji It means that current customer already has more than one order today. Try to test it with another customer account.

Comment: When I updated the cart for 2 Items still 1st exception is not showing

Comment: Still Same Error..

Comment: When I change date Its working Properly for past day orders, I checked for yesterday's order then it works properly... Do you have any Idea?

How to check orders for today?

Comment: @Lalji please, see my updated answer, I found one more issue in your conditions.

Comment: I only updated this code ((count($order->getItems()) - 1) >= 1) It is working Fine Now, If you did not help I would not have find it!!! Thanks a lot Man!!

Comment: @Lalji I'm glad to help you :) If it works, please, accept the answer as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Lalji intead of this code replace it with

```
if (count($order)>=1) {
   Mage::throwException('You already ordered today');
}else if($quote->getItemsCount()>=1){
   Mage::throwException('You can only Buy one product at a time. Please Change your Cart Items.');
 }
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Hi Murtaza, It is showing First Exception everytime 'You can only Buy one product at a time. Please Change your Cart Items.'

Comment: ok I will Update this

Comment: No Not working, I made changes according to another answer but Its showing Second Exception Now!

Comment: When I change date Its working Properly for past day orders, I checked for yesterday's order then it works properly...

Do you have any Idea?

Comment: intead of `date('2016-09-10 00:00:00')` please check with `date('Y-m-d')`